# Disconnecting checkboxes | clicked individually

Tags: flutter

I have two `Checkboxes`, one for agreeing to receive email promotions, and the other for terms and conditions. However, right now, when one is selected, they both are selected.

How can I separate them so that they have to be selected individually?

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Checkbox(
        value: receive,
        activeColor: Color(0xff33333D),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            receive = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      Text(
        "I agree to receive emails",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Checkbox(
        value: receive,
        activeColor: Color(0xff33333D),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            receive = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      Text(
        "I agree to the terms & conditions",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, both your checkboxes are updating the same `receive` variable:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  setState(() {
    receive = value;
  });
},
```

You should have two different variables instead.